# Need help to use LinkedIn API v2 (oauth2) with Python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I used code from here https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin with my id and key. If I run this code and go to localhost:8080 (i used this port) I get the following exception:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Aug/2018 13:25:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 65176)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\osads\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 647, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\osads\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\osads\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\server.py", line 646, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\osads\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 717, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\osads\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\server.py", line 426, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\osads\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\server.py", line 414, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "C:/Users/osads/PycharmProjects/python-linkedin-master/examples/http_api.py", line 60, in do_GET
    open_new_tab(liw.authentication.authorization_url)
  File "C:\Users\osads\PycharmProjects\python-linkedin-master\linkedin\linkedin.py", line 101, in authorization_url
    qsl = ['%s=%s' % (quote(k), quote(v)) for k, v in qd.items()]
  File "C:\Users\osads\PycharmProjects\python-linkedin-master\linkedin\linkedin.py", line 101, in <listcomp>
    qsl = ['%s=%s' % (quote(k), quote(v)) for k, v in qd.items()]
  File "C:\Users\osads\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 791, in quote
    return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
  File "C:\Users\osads\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 816, in quote_from_bytes
    raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
```

How to fix this?

UPD: code from linkedin.py

```
 @property
    def authorization_url(self):
        qd = {'response_type': 'code',
              'client_id': self.key,
              'scope': (' '.join(self.permissions)).strip(),
              'state': self.state or self._make_new_state(),
              'redirect_uri': self.redirect_uri}
        # urlencode uses quote_plus when encoding the query string so,
        # we ought to be encoding the qs by on our own.
        qsl = ['%s=%s' % (quote(k), quote(v)) for k, v in qd.items()]
        return '%s?%s' % (self.AUTHORIZATION_URL, '&'.join(qsl))
```

Comment: You're just using on of python-linkedin's examples? It's probably worth posting the relevant part of the example please so we can see what's going on. But can you look at the lines of linkedin.py to see what it's trying to do, and what the bad value is at that point?

Comment: Yes, i use examples and all the changes that I made it entered my number and key and choose  another port: PORT = 8080

LINKEDIN_API_KEY = ''       # my key
LINKEDIN_API_SECRET = ''    # my secret.
linkedin.py code added to question

Answer (score 0):

The value of this entry

```
'state': self.state or self._make_new_state()
```

is a boolean.
`quote` expects a string.

This is your error in a nutshell:

```
from urllib.parse import quote
quote(True)
```

I dont know what exactly you are doing, but this would fix your error (and possibly spawn a couple of new ones).

```
'state': str(self.state or self._make_new_state())
```

Comment: No, after changes was made it works with the same results

Comment: Is any of the other values something else than a string?

Comment: there is None in 'state'

Comment: i'm not sure but i thing it happens because of this: Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 65176). Port 65167 is used, not 8080 which i chose, and i don't know why

Comment: You get the same error when you convert all values in `qd` to `string`s?

Comment: state = {NoneType} None. Yes, i get the same excepions. There isw nothing in every value in qd